# ubuntu sound quality and dynamic on dell

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell

Having the most recent ubuntu on dell 5591, the sound quality misses all it s dynamic that windows has. Is there a driver to boost and bring all the dynamic to this sound ?

Audio:
Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-33-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

The sound comes out yes, but in such a low level without any sort of quality. It s the worst sound I have ever had.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: sound is not half of what comes out from windows. horrible setup.